# Issues with installing drupal from bitnami

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

This is my first time installing Drupal from xampp/Bitnami.

I finished the installation and then wanted to open the Drupal on the browser, but it is not opening; instead I am getting this error message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bitnami_drupal7.semaphore' doesn't exist: SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of C:\fastox\apps\drupal\htdocs\includes\lock.inc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have given prefix to your table names but it isnt configured properly in your drupal sites settings.php

you can find the settings.php file at *sitepath*\sites\default\

modify it to add the appropriate prefix in your database